# Java source for Architectural Constrain rule as starting point for a custom rule implementation

Tags: sonarqube

Is the ArchitecturalContraint rule implemented in Java, and could I see this code as a starting point for a custom rule?

Answer (score 1):

Sonar java plugin is fully open source and all the sources can be found on github : https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-java

So architectural constraint can be found here : https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-java/blob/master/java-checks/src/main/java/org/sonar/java/checks/ArchitectureCheck.java

If you want to implement a custom rule for java in java I suggest to read this part of documentation : 
http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Custom+Rules+for+Java

Comment: The documentation link is broken

Comment: Thanks! fixed it !